# Codemirror Simple Mode - Regex lookbehind and lookahead does not work

Tags: javascript, latex, codemirror

I just implemented a simple mode to recognize latex code.
Here is an code example that could be highlighted:

```
\documentclass{test}
```

There should be everything blue, except of the 'test' what should be purple. This is how my implementation looks like atm:

```
const CodeMirror = require('codemirror')

CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("simplemode", {
    start: [
        {
            regex: /(?<=\{).+?(?=\})/,
            token: 'argument'
        },
        {
            regex: /%.*/,
            token: 'comment'
        },
        /*{
            regex: /\\.*{.*}/,
            token: 'tag'
        },*/
        {
            regex: /\$.*\$/,
            token: 'math'
        }
    ],
    meta: {
        dontIndentStates: [],
        lineComment: '%'
    }
})
```

I removed the tag part, because I thought it would overlap with the tag. Anyways, even if all regexes match perfect in regex testers for javascript, the lookahead and lookbehind do not work.
Is there any workaround, fix, mistake?